# Creating std threads in C++ crashes the program

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, std

Whenever I execute the following piece of code using threads, the program has this error:

Debug Error!
Program: ... /path/to/.exe

abort() has been called

I want to create a thread that calls a member function. Here is the function I am using:

```
void ServerVote::createConnexionThreads()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 50; ++i)
    {
        m_connexionThreads.push_back(&(std::thread(&ServerVote::acceptConnection,*this, i)));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 50; ++i)
    {
        m_connexionThreads[i]->join();
    }
}
```

I can provide additional code if required. When using the debugger, I find that the program crashes right after the first thread is created, after the thread is pushed_back. ~thread() is then called and it crashes inside this function. Here is the vector declaration:

```
std::vector<std::thread*> m_connexionThreads;
```

I am using Visual Studio 2015. The acceptConnection function has a while(true) inside it and is planned to be terminated later.

Edit:

Thank you for your answers, but I cannot compile when using a thread object instead of a pointer. So when I try to push into this vector:

```
std::vector<std::thread> m_connexionThreads;

for (int i = 0; i <= 50; ++i)
{
        m_connexionThreads.push_back((std::thread(&ServerVote::acceptConnection,*this, i)));
}
```

I get this error while compiling:

```
error C2280: 'std::thread::thread(const std::thread &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

Comment: You are trying to populate a container with pointers to temporary objects you create in a loop. Not very likely to work.

Answer (score 3):

You should not try to use address of the temporary in any context. As a matter of fact, this is a bug in MSVC which allows this code. Any standard-conforming compiler would produce an error here.

Instead, you should use the thread object like this (see my edit below the code on why this is preferred):

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

void acceptConnection(int);

void foo() {
  std::vector<std::thread> vec;
  for (int i = 0; i <= 50; ++i)
        vec.push_back(std::thread(acceptConnection, i));
}
```

Why this approach is preferred over using an allocated pointer to the thread object? There are multiple benefits:

1. It is less typing - and even if nothing else, all things being equal (though they are not!) less typing wins over more typing.
2. It takes caution to use the pointers. For instance, you shouldn't use the raw pointer as vector data type, you should use `unique_ptr` to ensure automatic memory cleanup - which makes the syntax even uglier!
3. Using dynamically allocated memory is a drag on performance. You are hit twice - first time when you allocate memory, second time when you free it. Why suffer this penalty?

Comment: Thank you, but the reason I tried using pointers to threads instead of the thread object is because my code does not compile when I use thread object. It says that I am attempting to reference the copy constructor of std::thread (which is deleted).

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a local instance of thread in stack, taking its address and pushing it to the vector. The thread object will be deleted on exit of the method, so you will be left with a pointer to a deleted object.

You should use `new` to create the thread object in heap so it will not be deleted on method exit, or not use pointers to thread objects.

Comment: Seriously? New? Terrible advice.

Comment: You need an explanation? Stay tuned for an edit on my answer.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, if he wants to store pointers, it needs an explanation why not.

Comment: Apparently, he DOES NOT need to store pointers. Most likely, OP simply doesn't know what to do here. There is no scenario whatsoever which would require one to store dynamically allocated pointers to std::thread.

Comment: @SergeyA That is why I used the word *want* and not *need*.

Comment: Your answer is rather straightforward: "You should use new to create the thread object in heap". OP _should not_ do this.

Comment: Actually, I use pointers to threads instead of threads because it does not compile if I use a thread object. See edits in my question.